# Why does ReSharper need to scan all files when converting a property to an auto property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, resharper, automatic-properties

Is there any difference between accessing a property that has a backing field

```
    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
```

versus an auto-property?

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

The reason I'm asking is that when letting ReSharper convert a property into an auto property it seems to scan my entire solution, or at least all aspx-files.

I can't see any reason why there should be any difference between the two from outside the class. Is there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compiler generates the backing field for Auto-Properties automatically, so no, there shouldn't be any difference.

ReSharper is scanning all the files, because if you have a `Partial` class defined, it could be using the backing field instead of the public property even though the code exists in physically different files.

For Example:

```
// MyClass.cs
public partial class MyClass
{
    int _id;
    public int ID { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
    public MyClass(int identifier)
    {
        ID = identifier;
    }
}

// MyClass2.cs
public partial class MyClass
{
    public void ChangeID(int newID) 
    {
        _id = newID;
    }
}
```

ReSharper must scan all files, since it has no way to know where a partial class might be defined.

Comment: +1 makes perfect sense why the OP would say it was scanning his ASPX.CS's since they're all partial, and the code in question is very likely a page.aspx.cs where the property is defined and hence partial.

Comment: Really nice explanation, I was almost ready to ask the OP whether he was sure if ReSharper actually does that

Comment: Why do files in a different project need scanning, as a Partial class must be defined in the same project?  Also ReSharper should be able to see from the class it's self if it is Partail as all "bits" of a partail class must be marked partail.

Comment: @Ian -- I'm not sure about files in other solutions, but ReSharper has no way of knowing the contents of a file until after it scans it, so it must scan ALL files to find any partial classes defined.